LDAXRB and STXRB instructions - what is the "exclusive access to the memory address" in ARM64?
I'm trying to better understand atomic instructions on the ARM64 architecture.
So I'm testing this simple C code, using MSFT intrinsic (compiled with VS C++ 2022):
long v = 0;
_interlockedbittestandset_acq(&v, 0);

This translated to the following assembly code:
    str     wzr, [sp]           ; store 0 in the variable
    mov     x10, sp
lbl:
    ldaxrb  w9, [x10]           ; load byte from [x10] into w9, set exclusive access
    orr     w8, w9, #1          ; w8 = w9 | 1
    stxrb   wip1, w8, [x10]     ; store byte from w8 in [x10], only if exclusive access

    cbnz    wip1, lbl           ; jump back to 'lbl' if wip1 != 0 (or, if we didn't have "exclusive access")

    dmb     ish                 ; "acquire" memory barrier, or _acq part of the intrinsic

I have several questions here, if you don't mind:

If we follow documentation for the ldaxrb instruction, it basically loads a byte from the address pointed by x10 into w9 (with zero extension to 32 bits) and marks the address pointed by x10 for "exclusive access". Then stxrb stores the byte from w8 into the memory address pointed by x10, only if we have "exclusive access to the memory address". And if so, sets wip1 to 0, otherwise to 1.
So my question is where is that "exclusive access" information kept?

And also what can change the "exclusive access" that I mentioned above?

Finally, what is the purpose of the dmb     ish instructions after the loop?


As an interesting aside, if I break with a debugger and try to step through that loop above, it seems like the cbnz instruction always takes the jump back to the lbl address. Or, in other words, my stepping through that loop with a debugger resets the "exclusive access". Otherwise, how else would you explain such a behavior?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional .  IIRC, the way ARM documents it , the CPU has a "monitor" with some granularity.  It checks that the CPU never lost exclusive ownership of the cache line between the LL and SC.

@PeterCordes I've been testing it after I posted this. And it seems like that "exclusive access" flag is stored with a 0x40-byte memory address granularity on the CPU I'm testing it on. I wonder if that's the size of a cache line ... Still, how many of these can a CPU core remember ... Or is it stored in DDR ...

@c00000fd Only one at a time per thread.

dmb is a memory barrier instruction to tell the processor not to reorder memory accesses.

@RaymondChen: ldaxrb is an acquire load, already sufficient.  GCC compiles a.fetch_or(1, acquire) to just a retry loop with an acquire LL, relaxed SC.  https://godbolt.org/z/ojhG4cc9W MSVC compiles the same source with a dmb ish like the OP's seeing _interlockedbittestandset_acq.  That's atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst), stronger even than a seq_cst RMW operation, much stronger than the docs stated use-case of start/end of a critical section.  (I used GCC9; newer GCC either inlines ARMv8.1 single-instruction atomics or calls a helper function in hope they'll be available at run-time.)

@PeterCordes: You can get the inlined ARMv8.0 code with newer GCC by using -mno-outline-atomics.  https://godbolt.org/z/P7WdK7oYW

@c00000fd: The only way you've ever need more than one per core is if you could nest ldxr/stxr, which you can't.

@c00000fd: Yes, 64 bytes is the typical size of a cache line.

@PeterCordes: yes, I noticed too that MSFT compiler seems to be over aggressive with memory barriers.

@fuz you meant to say CPU core, right? Not a thread.

I don't see that this question really has anything to do with C++, so you might want to remove that tag.

@c00000fd I mean thread in the SMT sense.  One core can have multiple threads.

if related to how it was done in 32 bit arm, since they still use the AXI bus I assume this is true.  there is an exclusive access field on the bus and the virtual id.  the bus controller (whatever bus before the l2 cache or after) remembers the last virtual id and address (and length one would assume) many ldrex can happen, if the last one before the strex does not match then it does not return exclusive oka EXOKAY? (cant remember the signal name).  ARMs IP L1 cache in the core L2 cache if you bought it from them will do this, your (chip vendor) controller has to do it for multi-core

definitely does not consume the users memory for this, it is stored in the logic for each of these bus controllers, it was a bit difficult/tricky to actually test all the layers to see that the logic was properly implementing exclusive access  (you should not need to clrex in between). I want to remember it only needs to remember the last vid/address and not a buffer of them.  If you want to really understand exclusive access read the bus documentation.

some of the mcus dont bother and implement them as standard loads and stores.  and at one point arm said if you are uniprocessor (single core) simply return exokay as exclusive access is for multi core.  you can enable/disable caching and if you have an l2 enable/disable it and do some trivial experiments to see how each layer behaves from a single core/id and multiple (bare metal of course)...

The behavior of the load-exclusive and store-exclusive instructions is explained at length in the ARM A-profile Architecture Reference Manual (I'm reading version DDI0487-K.a), Section B2.17.
In brief, the load-exclusive instruction (I'll just use ldxr for example) sets a "monitor" on the address, or rather, on the "exclusive reservation granule" that contains it.  (Normally, "exclusive reservation granule" is just a fancy term for a single cache line, which indeed is commonly 64 bytes.) Then, the subsequent store-exclusive instruction (stxr) succeeds only if the monitor is still set.  To your question #2, the manual explains all the various events that could clear the monitor and thus cause the stxr to fail.
Actually, there are two monitors: a "local monitor" that is cleared only by various events happening on the same core that did the ldxr, and a "global monitor" which can be cleared by events on other cores.  Clearing either one causes the stxr to fail.

To your question #1, the monitor exists as some hardware internal to the CPU; the architecture spec doesn't specify how it is to be implemented, and it isn't something you can directly access architecturally, nor does it appear in the CPU's memory space.  Presumably the CPU has some internal registers to track its current state.  But there's normally only one monitor per core, so it's not like this requires a large amount of resources.  You can only monitor one address at a time.  So it's not possible to nest ldxr/stxr pairs, and you can't use it to perform atomic transactions involving multiple addresses.  That's not what it's for.
The monitor-clearing event that most people care about is a store to that address (or another address within the granule) from another core; this clears the global monitor.  This behavior is what ensures that the ldxr/stxr acts as an atomic read-modify-write operation on the address.
However, the local monitor is cleared by, among other things, an eret return-from-exception instruction.  This effectively ensures that if an interrupt or exception occurs in between the ldxr/stxr, then the stxr will fail and the section will need to be retried.  This behavior means that the ldxr/stxr section, in addition to being atomic with respect to accesses by other cores, is also atomic with respect to accesses on the same core.  So, for instance, you can safely use ldxr/stxr on memory that might be accessed asynchronously by an interrupt handler running on your own core.
(I believe that on 32-bit ARM, returning from an exception doesn't automatically clear the monitor, and so to be safe, the interrupt or exception handler needs to execute a CLREX instruction, whose sole purpose is to clear the monitor.)
To your "aside" question: in particular, since stepping in a debugger is implemented by having the CPU trap to the kernel's debug exception handler after every instruction, either using the CPU's single-step mode (see D2.11) or by temporarily replacing the following instruction with a brk instruction.  The kernel would then normally suspend the process being debugged, and do a context switch (on this core) to some other task that needs to run, as well as waking up the debugger process (either on this core or another one) so that it can show you what happened.  Even if all this stuff doesn't clear the local monitor of its own accord (e.g. by the kernel or the other tasks doing their own ldxr), when we eventually return to the debugged process to step another instruction, this is done by an eret that will certainly clear it.
So indeed, it's not possible to step your debugger through a ldxr/stxr section and have it succeed.  Instead, set a breakpoint following the stxr and let the process run free until it's hit.

To your question #3: The dmb ish instruction is a memory barrier, ensuring that all memory accesses that follow your stxrb will become visible to other cores after the stxrb store itself, and cannot be reordered with it (which otherwise would be allowed).  As was mentioned in the comments, this is not actually needed in order to have acquire semantics under the C++ memory model; it's sufficient that the exclusive load had an acquire barrier (i.e. it's ldaxrb instead of plain ldxrb)  (Actually, the weaker "Acquire-RCpc" ordering would suffice for C++ acquire, but it doesn't appear that ARM64 provides an exclusive load with this semantic.)  In fact, dmb ish wouldn't even be needed if you'd requested sequentially consistent ordering for this operation; then we could just use stxlrb, which despite its name, is just enough stronger than normal release ordering for C++ seq_cst (it can't be reordered with a later ldar).  AFAIK, the only way dmb ish would actually be needed is if you'd requested a std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst).

the only way dmb ish would actually be needed is if you'd requested a std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst). - or if you'd used _interlockedbittestandset instead of the _acq version.  Due to their x86 origins, MS's Interlocked functions aren't just seq_cst operations, they include a full memory barrier that orders all other operations in both directions, like x86's lock prefix on an RMW.  The whole point of the _acq suffix is to not do this (and to allow ldapr for a pure load version?), so it seems like a missed-optimization that there's a dmb ish.

Oh, I see, so MS adopts a stronger memory model than ISO C++ here.

I think it's a bug since they also include a dmb ish after a.fetch_or(1, acquire).  Unless for some reason they always strengthen every atomic RMW to be a full barrier, as a sop to bad code?  Including a dmb ish for _interlockedbittestandset_acq also contradicts their documentation the OP linked of being less strongly ordered.

https://godbolt.org/z/dTorzq6re shows the _nf form omitting the dmb ish, but the _acq one compiling as the OP showed.  stxr instead of stlxr, but then still dmb ish making it basically pointless.  Also showing GCC using dmb ishld for atomic_thread_fence(acquire), but MSVC still using dmb ish, so maybe the compiler internals have an acquire fence after the RMW?  It's an intrinsic, not a library function.

Anyway, the thing that's stronger than ISO C++ RMWs are MS functions like Windows InterlockedExchange and compiler intrinsic _InterlockedExchange.  The _acq / _rel versions of those are documented to only be acquire / release semantics, but yeah maybe they just are intentionally(?) making them acquire and release fences instead of just operations (and using dmb ish instead of ishld is a separate missed-optimization).  So actually yes, you're probably right that MSVC's memory model is stronger.

Just wanted to say thanks to you both for providing such helpful answers. Where are you learning all this?
